# get Last value of a column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the last value of a column(it is not an identity column) and increment it to the value of corresponding row number generated.

```
Select isnull(LAST_VALUE(ColumnA) over(order by ColumnA), 0) + 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA)
from myTable
```

I am calling my sp recursively hence why I thought of this logic.
But it is not working.

I basically wanted, for first time 1-9 for second run (if recursively being called 2 times) 10-19 and so on.

Comment: You should be using an `identity` column or `sequence`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total stab in the dark, but I suspect "not working" means "returning the current row's value." Don't forget that an `OVER` clause defaults to the window `RANGE BETWEEN PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` when one isn't explicitly specified and there is an `ORDER BY` (see [SELECT - OVER Clause (Transact-SQL) - ORDER BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#order-by)).

> #### ORDER BY
>
> ```sql
> ORDER BY *order_by_expression* [COLLATE *collation_name*] [ASC|DESC]
> ```
>
> Defines the logical order of the rows within each partition of the result set. That is, it specifies the logical order in which the window function calculation is performed.
>
> - If it is not specified, the default order is `ASC` and window function will use all rows in partition.
> - If it is specified, and a `ROWS`/`RANGE` is not specified, then default `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is used as default for window frame by the functions that can accept optional `ROWS`/`RANGE` specification (for example min or max).

As you haven't defined the window, that's what your `LAST_VALUE` function is using. Define that you want the whole lot for the partition:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(LAST_VALUE(ColumnA) OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), 0) + 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA)
FROM dbo.myTable;
```

Though what Gordon says in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993589/get-last-value-of-a-column-in-sql-server/65993647#comment116679877_65993589) is the *real* solution:

> You should be using an `identity` column or `sequence`.

This type of solution can (and will) end up suffering race conditions, as well as end up reusing "identities" when it shouldn't be.